# java naming class naming convention when it has acronyms?

Tags: java

If my class name contains any acronyms then how can i name?

Ex: **SomeDAO**   or **SomeDao**

Also, if any variable has acronyms, how can i name?

Ex: `private String appUID` or `private String appUid`

Thanks!

Comment: I would go with the first example. There is no correct answer. personal choice. Though the first example is common one.

Comment: Do not be scared to use longer names if they provide greater meaning, or resolve some confusion that might occur. e.g. drawingAppUid

Comment: if any abbrevation use first. othercase use second

Answer (score 3):

From [code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for java provided by oracle :

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML

As ***DAO*** is widely used and accepted , i would go for **SomeDAO**

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29):

> Treatment of acronyms in identifiers (e.g. the "XML" and "HTTP" in
>   XMLHttpRequest) varies. Some dictate that they be lowercased (e.g.
>   XmlHttpRequest) to ease typing and readability, whereas others leave
>   them uppercased (e.g. XMLHTTPRequest) for accuracy. A less popular
>   option is to always expand any acronyms (e.g.
>   ExtensibleMarkupLanguageHyperTextTransferProtocolRequest).

There is no ideal convention though but ideal approach should be to stick with whatever 
convention is choosen.

On a side not, following corner case could be considered:
com.x.y.XMLHttpReq
com.x.y.XMLHTTPReq

Assume that both of above were in different source folder and on-compilation bundled under one `jar` or `bin` folder:
Windows (case in-sensitive) - may override or compiler error (depends if bulk compiled)
*NIX (case sensitive) - fine

Answer (score 0):

I would use  `applicationUniqueIdentyfier`.