# class URLfinder or class URLFinder?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, convention

I was wondering what the naming convention is in instances where you pretty much have to use an acronym in the class name. I read the oracle documentation [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) but it did not offer much help.

Usually I name classes starting with an uppercase character and uppercase characters for each subsequent word (when there are no acronuyms), but in this case URLfinder is arguably more legible than URLFinder.

I don't want to use UniformResourceLocatorFinder because it is too verbose.

Comment: URLFinder would be good.  some do UrlFinder

Comment: OT, and dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2236807/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8277355/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5704737/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20046262/438992, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither; it should be `UrlFinder`.

This also avoids unfortunate names like `XMLHTTPRequest`, e.g., `XmlHttpRequest`, when common-sense naming says you have to glom them together.

Stuff in the Java APIs are inconsistent (e.g., `HttpURLConnection`).

The only way to make it right across everything is to treat acronyms as words.

Also, searched this on the interwebs and [found this discussion](http://blog.iprofs.nl/2011/01/25/capitalisation-of-abbreviations-in-java-names/) that says what I'm saying above but better and longer. It mentions things like `HTTPSID`: is that `HttpSid` or `HttpsId`? Only by treating acronyms as words can they be meaningfully distinguished.